# Semantically correct way to set initial values for JavaScript calculations obtained from server

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic graph that I render using a JavaScript library. A user is able to manipulate the data the graph is based on, but the initial values are set when the page is loaded. How do I convey this to the JS? I see several ways of doing it, but which one is semantically correct?

- Render the initial values into the `.js` file, server-side. (Possibly resulting in spaghetti code in server codes)
- Put `data-*` attributes on the relevant HTML elements, or use hidden `<input>`'s. (Dubious semantic validity)
- Load the data via AJAX when the HTML is fetched. (Extra requests to the server, results in blank graph if fails)

Comment: `data-` attributes may be just fine. Another option to consolidate the data would be to render a `<script type="application/json">`, put JSON into it, then in your JS, parse its `.textContent`

Comment: For the last option you could always decide to not render the graph until the data has arrived, and to render an error message for the user instead if the request fails.